# Problem in Gradle syncing after updating Android Studio 3.3.1 to 3.4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I just updated my Android Studio from version 3.3.1 to 3.4.2 and it ran into some problems with gradle syncing. Hope anyone can help.

Given below is the error occurred:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
>   Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars, returnDefaultValues=false}
>   Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
>   Cannot create mockable android.jar
>   invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Probably corrupted jar file. Try to delete it and re download it.

Comment: File -> Invalidate caches and restart sometimes fixes this when updating to a new android studio version

Comment: Either what PampaZiya said for invalidating caches should work or you can try cleaning and rebuilding, then restarting